# Update an existing Confluence page from a form without using a plugin

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I know it's possible to create a page from a form using the built-in 'Create from the template' macro but are my options for updating existing pages from a form limited to paying for a plugin, like ConfiForms or Frevvo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that it is dependent on the type of update you want to do. An example - you want to update some part of page recursively for n number of pages, you can write a script which uses confluence rest api to do so. Out-of-the-box and suggested way are plugins.

Comment: Yes using the confluence API is what I ended up doing. It seems like you can only access it from built-in macros (like HTML) via javascript/Ajax.